# Missing release in Apple Code?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, code-snippets

In this Apple code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

I can see that the session allocated at the start of the init method is not released.

Why ? Is there a reason to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple possible reasons come to mind:

- Apple meant to convert this sample to ARC, and forgot about or missed the `autorelease` call later in the same snippet.
- The ivar that gets `session` at the end of the `init` method is declared `@property (assign)`, and so they deliberately wanted to keep it retained for now. If I remember right, this is poor practice - they should have `autorelease`d session and declared the `@property (retain)`.
- They hand-`release` the `session` later. Not strictly poor practice, but certainly confusing and hard to read, and may lead to a bug in maintenance later (when someone loses track of the `retain`-`release` balance).
- This is genuinely a bug. Good catch!

In any event, you're right in that it's somewhat inconsistent with good memory management practices. It's hard to tell for sure, however, whether there's a definitive reason it's not released.